# Kivy. Refering to child in parent method

Tags: python, kivy

Hi let parent be parent widget ans child widget is its children how can i refer to child in parents method?
E.g child is a ball with move function and velocity vector and i want to have method which changes ball velocity in parent class.

Comment: Add an id to your child widget using `id: someid` in `.kv` file and then you can refer to the child from his parent by doing `self.ids.someid`.

Answer (score 0):

You use Kivy *ObjectProperty* to hook up to the class Ball in the parent class RootWidget as shown in the snippets.

[Programming Guide » Kv language](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html)

> Although the self.ids method is very concise, it is generally regarded as ‘best practice’ to use the ObjectProperty. This creates a direct reference, provides faster access and is more explicit.

## Snippets

### kv file

```
<Ball>:
    ...

<RootWidget>:
    ball: ball
    ...
    Ball:
        id: ball
```

### Python Script

```
class Ball(Widget):
    # velocity of the ball on x and y axis
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)

    def move(self):
       ...

class RootWidget(Widget):
    ball = ObjectProperty(None)
    ...
    self.ball.move(...)    # referencing the method move in class Ball
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answering, what about when i need to make hundreds of this balls? Is it a way to somehow do a loop or do i need to create hundred of ids and hundred of ball widgets?

Comment: Assuming that there is only one class Ball, then use a loop to instantiate each ball, and reference each object using `for child in reversed(self.container.children):` Please refer to example in [Add validation in form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50153595/python-add-validation-in-form/50160963#50160963)