# a way to know the type of widget in kivy(if its checkbox/textinput)

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I have a form and I want to have a reset button to reset all the fields to default.

I can go manually and reset every field I made, but I want to just do a for-loop on self.ids dict and reset .active/.text.

I need a way to know that the widget is a checkbox/textinput.

I would really appreciate the help from you kivy aficionados.

Comment: Please add the current code to your question. Currently it is hard to help you without any code or details about your attempts.

Comment: Please refer to examples of [isinstance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50153595/python-add-validation-in-form/50160963#50160963)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `isinstance`

```
def check_if_textinput(some_widget):
    return instance(some_widget, TextInput)
```

Comment: i tries that but it didnt work
il try later to show examples
eventually i just gave up and did it manually for all fields
its like 20 so not the end of the world